# bootstrap datetimepicker without time request

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have this jsp code (took by http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
   <input ng-model="utente.dt_nascita" type='text' class="col-sm-3 form-control" data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

And this code in my controller.js:

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                pickTime: false,
                autoclose : true
            });
```

I don't want the time! I want that datapicker asks only the date but it doesn't.

Comment: does that shows the `time` along with the date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved using:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Data di       nascita</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
             <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                 <input ng-model="utente.dt_nascita" type='text' class="col-sm-3 form-control" data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and:

```
 $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                startView: 'decade',
                minView: 'month',
                autoclose: true
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

since bootstrap-datetimepicker use moment.js, it is better to use [localized formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#localized-formats) from the official documentation. This way your 'date only' format will respect locale specifications of your application (if you set any).

For example, try :

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L'
});
```

From the docs, `'L'` refers to *Month numeral, day of month, year*.

Then, you can set `locale` parameter like this and simply forget its specifications, moment.js handles that for you :

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    locale: 'fr'
});
```

This will use *DD/MM/YYYY* format

Answer (score 1):

Supply custom format `format` when initializing `datetimepicker`. For example:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

See [Moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#localized-formats) for correct formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

For myself it works by setting it like this:

```
  $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      startView: 'month',
      minView: 'month',
      autoclose: true   
  });
```

So it says to start (startView) using month, and closing (minView) with month too

Answer (score 0):

I reslved using

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
startView: 'decade',
minView: 'month',
autoclose: true
});
```

I was using this datetimepicker: malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker